# How do I use a file or folder in one Git repo across multiple repos?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo (let's call it apples) that contains all my scripts that are used for various projects.

Now if I have another repo (let's call it oranges) specifically used for a singular project, how do I go about using a script that is contained within the apples repo?

I would rather not have to make a submodule of the entire apples repo. I would rather isolate a specific file or folder within the apples repo to be imported locally alongside or within the oranges repo.

Would I also be able to control the location of where I get to store the script from the apples repo within the oranges repo?

For example, if AAA.txt is stored in a folder called fruits in the apples repo, can I store that AAA.txt file within the root folder of the oranges repo?

Comment: I might question your repo design here.  Having the need to share files this across repos might imply that the files should not even be in separate repos.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, if the file being shared is a custom library used between various projects, where should such a file be stored? Is there a best practice for such a scenario?

Comment: Who/what would be changing the code in this library?  If it's even independent of these two projects, then it belongs in some kind of code, not Git, repository, such as Maven Central repo, NPM, etc.

Comment: Well an example would be an API call wrapper script. Those API calls can be used across various projects. It wouldn't make much sense to constantly have to recreate the same functionality for each project. So they simply call that one library that contains more and more API calls as required.

Comment: I would say in general if you have some functionality which needs to be used across two (or more) projects, then it should live in a project of its own, a library, a repo, a depedency, etc.

Comment: I was hoping to have a single repo that has all our scripts for all our projects in one place. Then just call the specific folders or files wherever required in other repos. I was using Perforce before moving to Git. It handles this functionality really easily because you simply map whatever files or folders you want wherever you'd like on your local directory. It seems much harder to achieve this same functionality in Git (if it is even possible at all)

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping to have a single repo that has all our scripts for all our projects in one place. Then just call the specific folders or files wherever required in other repos.

> I was using Perforce before moving to Git. It handles this functionality really easily because you simply map whatever files or folders you want wherever you'd like on your local directory. It seems much harder to achieve this same functionality in Git (if it is even possible at all)

This is not well suited for Git.
One possible workaround would be to create a symlink from your repository to the right file of folder of your "common utils" repository.

A more Git-like solution is to create [template repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-template-repository) which can then be cloned directly with the right structure/content.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like I'll have to go the symbolic link route. I'll try it out and update this question accordingly!